"Error reading from the server - read (104: Connection broken by the other side)" while trying to update Ubuntu 24.04 to Ubuntu 24.10
I was trying to update Ubuntu 24.04.1 to Ubuntu 24.10 and I got:
Failed to fetch http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_20240913.gita34e7a5f-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb 
Error reading from the server - read (104: Connection broken by the other side) [IP: 153.19.251.225 80]


Hi, today the problem disappeared, the distribution update was successful.I don't know why.

Your error message 104: Connection broken by the other side indicates that the problem was not your system. The problem was with the server at the other end.

after entering  into the browser http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_20240913.gita34e7a5f-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb a message appeared that the connection was being interrupted due to a security risk, but in the end the update of the distribution was successful.

Try to get this file manually by browser or wget:
wget http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_20240913.gita34e7a5f-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
and copy it to folder /var/cache/apt/archives
then start the update

Hi, I did wget..., but the server disconnected many times, as I mentioned earlier, I updated the distribution to 24.10.
